# How does Unity know where the character is facing?

Tags: unity, c#, rotation, transformation, quaternion

I just learned `Quaternion.LookRotation` and it's used for rotating an object.

I used it to face my character in the direction where it's moving, but I couldn't understand: how does Unity know which side of my character is the face?

I mean I don't specify front of my character but Unity knows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't know.

What it does is point the local z axis of the object (that's the blue arrow you see in the scene view when selecting its local transform gizmo) in the `forward` direction you pass to `LookRotation`, and the local y axis (green arrow) as close as possible to the `upwards` direction you pass, or world up if you didn't provide a second argument.

[image: Gizmo Toggles]

[image: Transform gizmo]

By convention in Unity, we call this blue arrow z direction "forward", and assets built for Unity will typically be set up so that they face along the z+ axis.

So this will "just work" as expected for any asset that's been set up to follow this convention. Not because Unity knows anything about the model, but because the model artist knows something about Unity.

There's an obvious exception to this though: in 2D, the blue "forward" axis points into the screen, and your character sprites might face right (red) or up (green) instead. For those, we either need to use `LookRotation` a bit differently, or make our own convenience function to point our chosen axis in the direction we want.

Comment: Firstly, thanks for your explanation. It is really useful and I understood too much thing. But I read it again and again and didn't understand first part exactly. 
What you mean is When we use `LookRotation` Unity takes Z and Y axis of first parameter (forward) and tries to look to what we pass to second parameter(upward) ?

Comment: No. Unity takes the blue axis of your object and points it toward the first argument, `forward`. Then, keeping the blue axis pinned in that direction, it twists the object around that axis to make the green axis point as close as possible to the second argument, `upwards`.

Comment: Really thanks too much. I did understand very well. I'm trying to understand for 4 hours and finally did. I tried to give upvote to you but couldn't.